# C# ComboBox string array with int

Tags: arrays, string, combobox, int

Well, the title is a bit confusing but I want to ask if it possible to have a array with string and int inside ?

For example:

```
string[] versions = new string[] { "Normal",1, "Expert",2, "Pro",3 };
comboBox.Items.AddRange(versions);
```

So if I would select Normal, the version integer would be set to 1. In my programm I got alot if items in my comboBox, and I don't want to have 50+ if functions to set the integer.

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an `Object` containing the `string` and `int` properties/fields. Try the following:

```
public class Version // You can replace "Version" with any name you'd like
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have an array of your Version-objects you can use:

```
Version[] versions = new Version[] {
    new Version { Name = "Normal", Value = 1 },
    new Version { Name = "Expert", Value = 2 },
    new Version { Name = "Pro", Value = 3 }
};
```

I couldn't tell which programming language you are using (although I assumed .NET C# based on the code given).